# Hosting on subdomain using URL or path pattern?

Tags: angular, subdomain, hosting

I have deployed an angular app at AWS instance, it has three flows in it. say:

- 12.345.6.789:4200/alpha
- 12.345.6.789:4200/beta
- 12.345.6.789:4200/gamma

Now I want to create subdomains for each one of the flow using my godaddy account, it will be something like:

- alpha.example.com
- beta.example.com
- gamma.example.com

I think it is achievable but how, that I don't know. If anyone is aware of how to do that, please point me in right direction, it is very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an Application Load Balancer in front of your EC2 instance? If so you can setup the path based routing and SSL there.

Answer (score 1):

create three distributions on cloudfront for

```
alpha.example.com
beta.example.com
gamma.example.com
```

then three resources on Gateway API to point to the and link them with cloudfront distributions:

```
12.345.6.789:4200/alpha
12.345.6.789:4200/beta
12.345.6.789:4200/gamma
```

now in you angular app, you can setup proxy which will map `/alpha -> alpha.example.com` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can it be done using godadday, because all of our DNS are configured there.

Comment: DNS can be at godaddy, no problem with that. Once you create a resource in Gateway API it will be available at some url, you can use this url as CNAME in your DNS, so all calls for subdomain will redirect to the particular resource. CloudFront part is optional, but you can achieve free TSL/SSL connection.